# Removing Variable of Standard Array after randomly choosing it

Tags: c#, arrays, list, c#-7.0

I want to remove a variable from an array after one is randomly chosen. Current code looks like this:

```
<Random random = new();
int exitScore = 0;

do{
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play RANDOM MAD LIBS? (Yes/No)");
string playerChoice = Console.ReadLine()!.ToLower()!;

if(playerChoice == "yes"){
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter the series of inputs requested, one at a time.");
Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 3 Names, Such as your own.");
string[] name = {$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}"};

Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 3 Adjectives.");
string[] adj = {$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}"};

Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 3 Action Verbs (Ending in -ing).");
string[] verb = {$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}"};

Console.WriteLine("Please Enter 3 nouns.");
string[] noun = {$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}",$"{Console.ReadLine()}"};

Console.WriteLine($"{name[random.Next(1,3)]} likes to hang out at the {noun[random.Next(1,3)]} and enjoys {adj[random.Next(1,3)]} {verb[random.Next(1,3)]}.");
Console.WriteLine($"{name[random.Next(1,3)]} likes to hang out at the {noun[random.Next(1,3)]} and enjoys {adj[random.Next(1,3)]} {verb[random.Next(1,3)]}.");
Console.WriteLine($"{name[random.Next(1,3)]} likes to hang out at the {noun[random.Next(1,3)]} and enjoys {adj[random.Next(1,3)]} {verb[random.Next(1,3)]}.");
}
else{exitScore++;}
}
while(exitScore < 1);
```

I've been attempting to store the chosen array variable into a separate variable to then not be included in a copied array to be chosen from next. I have also attempted turning it into a list, but that is a little advanced for me. Is there a better way to do that or is that the only option? I haven't been successful so far on any front.

Comment: There is no traces of removing anything from any arrays in the code posted - so it is very hard to understand what exactly you have problem with. As result I think standard duplicate for "RemoveAt for Array" should answer your question. If that is not the case please [edit] the question and provide an [mre] of the exact problem (not just dump of your current code - i.e. none of the `Console.ReadLine` seem to be related to problem you have and should be replaced with inline constants).

Comment: You can't _remove_ values from an array. Consider using `List<string>` instead of `string[]`. Do you know what `Random.Next(1,3)` will return, and do you know how array indexing works in C#? Hint, the call to `Next` will only return one of the numbers 1 or 2. Array indexing starts with zero in C#, so, for example, you `adj` array has items `adj[0]`, `adj[1]` and `adj[2]`

Comment: Additionally make sure you indeed require C# 7 specific answer - while not quite limiting as usual C# 2 tags from new users it is still a restriction that you likely don't actually have.